# Getting coefficients of a polynomial mod as an int list in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I am attempting to get an `int list` of coefficients of a remainder of the division of two polynomials. I have been attempting to use `mod` from `Polynomial.thy` on two polynomials of type `int poly`. However, I am getting the error:

```
Type unification failed: No type arity int :: field
```

My function is:

```
fun testFunc :: "int poly ⇒ int poly ⇒ int list"
where
  "testFunc p q = int_list (coeffs (p mod q))"
```

Where `int_list` simply converts a list of reals to a list of ints by flooring each element:

```
fun int_list :: "real list ⇒ int list"
where
  "int_list [] = []" |
  "int_list lst = [floor (hd lst)] @ int_list (tl lst)"
```

This works when I define my function as:

```
fun testFunc :: "'a::field poly ⇒ 'a poly ⇒ int list"
where
  "testFunc p q = int_list (coeffs (p mod q))"
```

However, the two arguments being passed into the function are specifically of type `int poly`. If I pass in two polynomials `'a::field poly` and `'a poly` using the second definition, then an `'a list` is returned and I cannot run my int_list function.

If I change `int_list`'s signature to `'a list => int list`, then I must use `int_of` on each element, which ultimately does not evaluate the integers in my list. (i.e. I get something like `[int_of 2, int_of 3]` rather than `[2, 3]`, and when I try to do something with those lists, it is returned with the `int_of x` expression rather than an evaluation)

Is it possible to get an `int list` of the coefficients of the modulo of two polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `floor` function requires a type that's been instantiated as class `floor_ceiling` ([Archimedean_Field.thy#l140](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4a332500e4/src/HOL/Archimedean_Field.thy#l140)).

So, I make your `int_list` as general as possible with `'a::floor_ceiling`:

```
fun int_list :: "'a::{floor_ceiling} list => int list" where
  "int_list [] = []" |
  "int_list lst = [floor (hd lst)] @ int_list (tl lst)"
```

The type `poly` has been instantiated for class `ring_div`, which gives it the `mod` function, but only for `'a::field` ([Polynomial.thy#l1467](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/8f4a332500e4/src/HOL/Library/Polynomial.thy#l1467)).

Because `testFunc` uses `int_list`, I make your `testFunc` as general as possible with `'a::{field,floor_ceiling}`:

```
fun testFunc :: "'a::{field,floor_ceiling} poly => 'a poly => int list"
  where
  "testFunc p q = int_list (coeffs (p mod q))"

value "testFunc ([:1,2,3:]::real poly) ([:5,6,7:]::real poly)"
  (*OUTPUT: "[- (2::int), - (1::int)]" :: "int list" *)
```

A few information commands:

```
declare[[show_sorts, show_consts]]
print_classes 
  (*At 'class ring_div', it shows ' poly :: (field) ring_div'.*)  
print_dependencies floor_ceiling  
print_dependencies ring_div
```